# ls command: how to ignore case without globbing

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards

I use the `shopt -s nocaseglob` command to ignore case, but it seems like it doesn't work if I use a string without glob.

[image]

Just a question out of curiosity, is it possible to ignore case without globbing?
i.e. `ls a` would output both **a** and **A**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with `ls` no. You could, however, use something like these:

```
$ ls [Aa]
$ find . -iname a
$ echo [aA]
```

The reason behind this is that the `shopt` command only affects how globs are expanded by the shell. So, when you run `ls *a` *after* running the `shopt` command, that gets expanded by your shell to

```
ls a A
```

So, as @Kevin said, the glob is expanded *before* being passed to `ls`, therefore the `nocaseglob` will have no effect when you give a simple string and not a glob.

Answer (score 2):

No. Glob expansion is handled by the shell before `ls` is even invoked.